# Bool in URL encoded parameters encodes as 0 and 1 with Alamofire in Swift3

Tags: json, swift, swift3, alamofire, put

I use alamofire with put method, for send bool value, but when I try to print the return of my request it transform from bool value to an int.

But in my database I really neeed to stock a bool value. Here is my code

```
func sendNewData(key:String, index: Int, value: Bool, sectionName: String) -> Void {
    let url:String = "\(self.API_URL_BASE)\(API_URL_SETTINGS)"

    var parameters: Parameters
    parameters = [
        sectionName: [
            key: value,
        ]
    ]
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .put, parameters: parameters, headers: Api.headers).responseJSON
    { response in
        if (response.error == nil)
        {
            let json = JSON(response.result.value!)
            if (json["status"].stringValue == "ok")
            {
                self.getSettings()
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print(response.error)
        }
    }
}

func getSettings() -> Void {
    let url:String = "\(self.API_URL_BASE)\(API_URL_SETTINGS)"
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, headers: Api.headers).responseJSON
        { response in
            if (response.error == nil)
            {
                let json = JSON(response.result.value!)
                print(json)
            }
            else
            {
                print(response.error as Any)
            }
    }
}
```

getSettings method return me:

> {
>        "status" : "ok",
>        "data" : {
>            "misc" : {
>                "beInAnonymousPanel" : "0"
>            }
>        }
>    }

Instead of:

> {
>        "status" : "ok",
>        "data" : {
>            "misc" : {
>                "beInAnonymousPanel" : true
>            }
>        }
>    }

I find some other topic and it's before swift3 and they got no good solution.

Edit: I use swiftyjson

Comment: Brother check your web service, this is correct way to return bool value as 0 or 1. If you want to get `true` or `false' then you should add `true or False` as value of `beInAnonymousPanel` from web service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found my answer, I forgot to encode my parameters:

```
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .put, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default,  headers: Api.headers).responseJSON
    { response in.. }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it, convert the int to bool and save it or use it.
Convert like :

```
let intVar = 1
let boolVar = Bool(intVar as NSNumber)

print(boolVar) // true
```

Comment: No this solution doesn't work for me it's still stock an int in my database, I can only have bool.

Comment: In database you're storing as bool or int?
If you're storing it in core data then it'll shown as the 0 or 1, but in model you can get it as true or false

Comment: In database I store Bool

Answer (score 0):

if you making a request with alamofire and using URLEncoding for an encoder convert bool to String using String(Variable) but if you use JSONEncoding do nothing